# Andorid Studio java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I know this is not first question about this error. I've searched for the answer in everywhere but i couldn't find the solve. when i run the code i get this exception;

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Doviz> dovizs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://finans.truncgil.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        DovizApi dovizApi = retrofit.create(DovizApi.class);

        Call<List<Doviz>> call = dovizApi.getDoviz();

      

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Doviz>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Doviz>> call, Response<List<Doviz>> response) {
                System.out.println("deneme");
                List<Doviz> responseList= response.body();
                dovizs = new ArrayList<>(responseList);
                System.out.println(dovizs.get(0).USD);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Doviz>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Java Class

```
public class Doviz {

    @SerializedName("Buying")
    public String USD;

}
```

Interface

```
public interface DovizApi {
    @GET("today.json")
    Call<List<Doviz>> getDoviz();
}
```

the list i use
https://finans.truncgil.com/v3/today.json

I have been dealing with this for days. I hope we can solve it

Comment: this error line 1 column 2 path $ is because of your API recheck your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's Happening?**

- The root of the API response is a JSONObject and not the JSONArray.
- v3 is missing from the API URL.

**Solution**

Update Interface

```
public interface DovizApi {
    @GET("v3/today.json")
    Call<HashMap<String, Object>> getDoviz();
}
```

Update Response Model(Doviz)

```
public class Doviz {
   @SerializedName("Buying")
   public String buying;

   // Similarly you can add other keys here
}
```

Update Retrofit Call

```
Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call = dovizApi.getDoviz();
call.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<String, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call, Response<HashMap<String, Object>> response) {
            HashMap<String, Object> responseModel = response.body();

            // Iterate all the currencies
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : responseModel.entrySet())
                if(entry.getValue() instanceof LinkedTreeMap) { // Since the first element is of type String i.e. "Update_Date"
                    Doviz doviz = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(((LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue())), Doviz.class);
                    System.out.println("Currency = " + entry.getKey() +
                                     ", Buying = " + doviz.buying);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried but i get this exception. " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Set java.util.HashMap.entrySet()' on a null object reference " what can i do?

Comment: @DoğukanÇiftçi I have updated the answer after verifying. It should work now. Kindly update the codebase mentioned above under the Solution section.

Comment: You're the best thank you so much it's working now.
But i want to ask you personal question. Why we use HashMap? What could we use instead of HashMap? What is mean this code ''Doviz doviz = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(((LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue())), Doviz.class);'' . How did you learn these? Yes the problem is fixed but i didn't understand how it happened. I still can't write this code myself, how can i learn? Again thank you so much have a healthy days.

Comment: @DoğukanÇiftçi Glad to hear that the problem is solved. The reason for using HashMap is because your response is having custom keys (not fixed keys) for currencies. You can learn more by digging into the Gson library.

Comment: thank you for help but i need your help again because i didn't understand exactly what we do. I have to use this varriables (currency name and buying) in recyclerview. How can I use that ? Everything's so confused in my head. ArrayLists, Lists,HashMaps ...

Answer (score 0):

Check point

1. Type

Json looks like below

```
{
   "Update_Date":"2021-05-12 16:00:01",
   "USD":{
      "Buying":"8,3681",
      "Type":"Currency",
      "Selling":"8,3735",
      "Change":"%1,13"
   },
   ...
}
```

It's not `<List>` and `USD` is one of key in json

so the `Call<List<Doviz>>`  should change to `Call<Doviz>`

2. DTO (Doviz)

You may want `Buying` value of `USD`.
You're DTO(Doviz) should has property as another DTO like this

```
  class Doviz {
        @SerializedName("USD")
        CurrencyInfo usd;
       
        // else like this
        @SerializedName("EUR")
        CurrencyInfo eur;

        //...
  }

  class CurrencyInfo {
        //if Path(/v3) included
        @SerializedName("Buying")
        String buying;

        //if Path (/v3) not included 
        @SerializedName("Alış")
        String _buying;

       // else.. 
 }
```

```
interface DovizApi{
        @GET("/v3/today.json")
        fun getEnDoviz(): Call<Doviz>
}
```

```
Call<Doviz> call = dovizApi.getDoviz();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Doviz>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Doviz> call,Response<Doviz>response){
                Doviz doviz = response.body();
                CurrencyInfo info = doviz.getUsd();
                System.out.println(info.getBuying());
            }
..
}
```

It worked well.

Comment: when i did it i get another error. "List<Doviz> responseList= response.body();" this part is not working.it says ''java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.parsingjson.Doviz cannot be cast to java.util.List''

Comment: `List<Doviz>` should change to `Doviz`. It's not List